# Unknown URL Type: Image Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My error:

> File "C:/Users/hp dv4/PycharmProjects/project/imagescrap.py", line
>   22, in 
>           imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen(img_src).read())
>       ValueError: unknown url type: '/img/logo_with_text.png'

I am getting this error while crawling through the specified website whereas, this same code works fine with some other website.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata


i = 1
soup = make_soup("http://ioe.edu.np/")

unique_srcs = []
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    if img.get('src') not in unique_srcs:
        unique_srcs.append(img.get('src'))
for img_src in unique_srcs:
    filename = str(i)
    i = i + 1
    imagefile = open(filename + '.png', 'wb')
    imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen(img_src).read())
    imagefile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error messages says:

```
 unknown url type: '/img/logo_with_text.png'
```

add `http://ioe.edu.np/` in front of `img_src` and it should work

Answer (score 1):

the above code will encounter one more error.

you are trying to save every file with .png extension, which may make the files unreadable.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata


base_url = "http://ioe.edu.np/"
soup = make_soup(base_url)

unique_srcs = []
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    if img.get('src') not in unique_srcs:
        unique_srcs.append(img.get('src'))

for i, img_src in enumerate(unique_srcs):
    print(img_src)
    filename = str(i)
    extension = img_src.split('.')[-1]
    with open(filename+'.'+extension, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(urllib.request.urlopen(base_url+img_src).read())
```

---

few idiomatic python suggestions:

- use enumerate instead of trying to manage a counter.
- use the with-open construct which takes care of closing your file.

one other thing you could do to further improve:

- use a set instead of a list, so that you don't download the same file twice.